# How to add properties file into Java project?

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I am using `.properties` file for my project and Netbeans 6.9.1 IDE. How can I add my properties file into the code?

```
  String prop="c:\\Config.properties";
    Properties Config= new Properties();
   Config.load(new FileInputStream(prop));
   f1=Config.getProperty("f1");
   f2=Config.getProperty("f2");
```

How can I define my Build path instead of `"c:\\Config.properties"`?

Is there any way to add this file directly to the project?

Comment: Have you tried using [Java Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) or [Java Preferences](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html)?

Answer (score 4):

You could put the config.properties into one of your packages and then define the path to your properties file relative.

```
 ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream ("your/app/package/config.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Niraj,

Do not use the hardcoded path for your properties file. Either get the file path from the project properties or using the build/runtime values.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help: [Adding properties](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html?page=1)